# Twitter API working in Postman but not in AppScripts (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, postman, urlfetch

My twitter API call is working in Postman but not in AppScripts. I have the authorization set in both and am using the same url.

```
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          headers:{
            Authorization: "Bearer ..."
          },
        })
  console.log("res is", res);
  return res;
```

This returns "res is {}"

But in Postman, the same call with the same URL and the same Authorization token returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "...",
    "name": "...",
    "username": "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: `res` is `HTTPResponse` object. You need to get the content from it. See See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/urlfetch/info) for free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TheMaster for your response.

```
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers:{
        Authorization: "Bearer ..."
      },
    })

return res.getContentText();
```

This fixes it.